# JSch Disconnect Button

Tags: java, netbeans, jsch

I've being teached myself Java over the last few weeks (quite possibly doing something wrong)!

I have developed a simple program that connects to a database lists locations. I can connect to them, using JSCH to set up a tunnel. So I can VNC onto it.

This all works fine. However, my issue is with the disconnect part of this.

I have a Public Void called WinConnect, this is fired if the button for connection had been clicked cliked and as above works as thread.

On the disconnect button I tried:

Current Part of the relivant button code

```
private void jButtonDisconnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    this.channel.disconnect();
    this.session.disconnect();
```

}

- Session session.disconnect(); //says expected; and cannot find symbol
        method disconnect
- Session.session.disconnect(); //this says cannot find varible session
- JSch.session.disconnect //this says cannot find varible session

and so on, none of them do work. Netbeans says there are errors within the code. Clearly my lack of knowledge means im doing something wrong, probably something obvious!

All Of WinConnect:

```
 private void WinConnect(){
  String SshPortNumb = (String)SshPort.getSelectedItem();
  int SshPortNum = Integer.parseInt(SshPortNumb);
  String PcIpNum = (String)PcIp.getText();
  String host = (String)SiteIp.getText();
  String VncPortNumb = VncPort.getText();
  int VncPortNum = Integer.parseInt(VncPortNumb);
  String user = (String)UserName.getText();
  String PasswordVal = (String)Password.getText();
  String VncPathpre = VncPath.getText();
  String VncPathdat = "\""+VncPathpre+"\"";

try{
  JSch jsch=new JSch();

  jsch.setKnownHosts("known_hosts");


  this.session=jsch.getSession(user, host, SshPortNum);

  String passwd = PasswordVal;
  this.session.setPassword(passwd);

  UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo(){
    public void showMessage(String message){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String message){
      Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
      int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                                           message,
                                           "Warning", 
                                           JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                                           null, options, options[0]);
      return foo==0;
    }

  };
jButtonDisconnect.setEnabled(true);
jButtonConnect.setEnabled(false);
  this.session.setUserInfo(ui);

  this.session.connect(30000);  

  this.session.setPortForwardingL(7051, PcIpNum, VncPortNum);

  this.channel=session.openChannel("shell");

  this.channel.setInputStream(System.in);

  this.channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

  this.channel.connect(3*1000);

}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

}

```
public class RemoteDesktop extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private Session session;
private Channel channel;
```

EDIT: Guess because the varible Session is in the winconnect and not in the button it can't find it?

Edit2: After trying suggestion below it just locks up when clicking disconnect

Edit3: Right the new code should work, but there appears to be an issue with session.disconnect, if i call session.delPortForwardingL(7051); it works but im not sure if the connections are still active, unsure why session.disconnect does not!

Edit4: Checked the server and the connecetions are still in place it does just remove the fowarding stoppign my VNC, not good :(

Edit5: Checked if calling the session.disconnect was actually working it does, it however causes my program to lock up for some reason

Comment: Can provide the more source code? What is the error text of the message, came from Netbeans?

Comment: Ive added some more bits, but there isnt more more to add i think im clearly missing something major to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did post just a piece of source code, I only could guess. Based on the error messages, the thing is that method `.addActionListener()` creates an own variable scope. So you haven't an access of parents context.

Try to move the variable `Session session` to the global scope, something like this:

```
public class YourJavaClass
{
  private Session session;

  public static void main()
  {
    ...
  }

  private void connect(String location)
  {
   try
   {
     JSch jsch=new JSch();

     jsch.setKnownHosts(location);

     this.session=jsch.getSession(user, host, SshPortNum);

     String passwd = PasswordVal;
     this.session.setPassword(passwd);
     this.session.connect(30000);  

     session.setPortForwardingL(7051, PcIpNum, VncPortNum);
  }

  private void yourGuiMethod()
  {
   ...
   jButtonDisconnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
   {
     public void jButtonDisconnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
     {
        this.session.disconnect();
     }
   });  
   ...
  }
}
```

You can downvote my answer if you want. Though keep in mind, at this timepoint you haven't posted enough source code. So I was only able to guess.

Comment: What parts would you like to see, i can throw it all in however theres Alot of code mostly illrelivant. I have tested as above and it seems to lock the GUI up without any errors when hitting disconnect

Comment: With Java you can create a complex code structure. So a beginner can be catched by lot of traps.

Comment: Indeed, no end of googling has been done while ive been triyng to learn java! Worst part was that i had it working using cmd prompt and plink, but thats not multi platform which is why i switched to using JSch, which is nicer if i understood it better :)

Comment: It appears that Disconnecting the session is whats locking up my program not sure why however :(

Comment: Right what you suggeted work a treat, thank you very much even for working with my limited code, after doing what you suggested it casued another issue which was not realated to what you gave me, but i found the answer on another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135165/sshclient-jsch-bufferedinputstream-lock